# Occasional MySQL query Error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file-io

I have a php file that has to be loaded as a web page.
This page is 17Kb in size.
It has a php mysql query script inside.

the problem now, sometimes my mysql_query() lines gives an error.
When being refreshed, it works again.
It just have an error sometimes on that same line.
I check the query string and it was okay, for if that was the problem the error should happen all the time.

any idea?...

I was thinking maybe it was the file that has not been loaded completely.
And if that so, anyone to help me?... thanks.

Comment: @Reigel - what error do you see?

Comment: Ok, i did some refreshing and after about 10 refresh it got me this, "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /var/www/vhosts/media-secure.net/subdomains/secure/httpsdocs/freshmodules.php on line 25" but when I refresh again it works fine again.

Comment: this is the query string if it helps: "SELECT project_name, project_id FROM tbl_todo_project WHERE project_id IN (SELECT project_id FROM tbl_todo_queue WHERE groupid = '" . $_SESSION['login_id'] . "')  OR project_id IN (SELECT project_id FROM tbl_todo_project, tbl_todo_group WHERE tbl_todo_group.group_id = tbl_todo_project.project_groupid AND tbl_todo_group.group_packageid LIKE '%" . $_SESSION['login_id'] . "%') ORDER BY project_name";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource."

Sound like you have a problem with mysql connection. Try the the following code, after you  called connect function, try to print out the error message.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: ok, tried this.. and for some time it could not connect to the host. So is there a way to make a reconnection?

Comment: most likely your host's mysql connection is maxed out. How busy is your site? If the connections are made by your own page then you might want to move to a better server. If not you should ask for server support. mysql_stat() will be also useful, it will return current active open connections server wide, of course that need a valid connection too. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql_error() to get more details about the error that's currently occuring.
Just below the line that triggers the error, add:

```
echo mysql_error();
```

Comment: Remember to remove when going to production!